# How to iterate an int column for each distinct value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I've been trying a query to update my current database but I can't figure out how to do it. I've been trying with cursors but I can't find a way to isolate each row and not set all the rows of the distinct column to the same value.

Here is what I have in my database:

```
RecoNumber   Item
ABIBAQC-01   1
ABIBAQC-01   1
ABIBAQC-01   1
ABIBAQC-02   1
ABIBAQC-03   1
ABIBAQC-03   1
```

And I would like it to become:

```
RecoNumber   Item
ABIBAQC-01   1
ABIBAQC-01   2
ABIBAQC-01   3
ABIBAQC-02   1
ABIBAQC-03   1
ABIBAQC-03   2
```

Like I said, I've tried with a cursor but I am missing something to make it work properly.

```
DECLARE @NUMBER INT
DECLARE @RECO NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @RECO_OLD NVARCHAR(10)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT RecoNumber
FROM Workbook2014_Test.dbo.Reco

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @RECO
SET @NUMBER = 1
SET @RECO_OLD = @RECO

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE Workbook2014_Test.dbo.Reco
    SET Item = @NUMBER 
    WHERE RecoNumber = @RECO

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @RECO
    IF(@RECO != @RECO_OLD)
        SET @NUMBER = 1
    ELSE
        SET @NUMBER = @NUMBER + 1
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RecoNumber ORDER BY RecoNumber) AS UPD_Item
              FROM  YourTable
              )
UPDATE cte
SET Item = UPD_Item
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row. `PARTITION BY` is optional, but used to start the numbering over for each value  in a given field or group of fields, ie: if you `PARTITION BY Some_Date` then for each unique date value the numbering would start over at 1. `ORDER BY` of course is used to define how the counting should go, and is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

You can `SELECT * FROM cte` first to observe the new values before running the `UPDATE`, you may have other field values you'd prefer to `ORDER BY`.